# My recursive function not properly remove all children

Tags: javascript, recursion, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

This code remove all container's children, and set every children = null to free the memory. The structure of *myElement* is not always the same, so i would like a dynamic thing.

```
var cont1 = myElement.children.length;
for(var i = cont1 - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
    var cont2 = myElement.children[i].children.length;
    for (var j = cont2 - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        var cont3 = myElement.children[i].children[j].children.length;
        for (var k = cont3 - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
            var cont4 = myElement.children[i].children[j].children[k].children.length;
            for (var w = cont4 - 1; w >= 0; w--) {
                myElement.children[i].children[j].children[k].remove(myElement.children[i].children[j].children[k].children[w]);
                myElement.children[i].children[j].children[k].children[w] = null;
            }
            myElement.children[i].children[j].remove(myElement.children[i].children[j].children[k]);
            myElement.children[i].children[j].children[k] = null;
        }
        myElement.children[i].remove(myElement.children[i].children[j]);
        myElement.children[i].children[j] = null;
    }
    myElement.remove(myElement.children[i]); //i loop
    myElement.children[i] = null; //i loop
}
```

This is my recursive test function.
Seems to work only in part. The first level is not deleted , it would be the **i** loop of the old code. How i can remove also that level of children?

```
function deleteRecursive(element){
    if(element.children.length > 0){
        for(var i = element.children.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
            if(element.children[i].children.length > 0){
                deleteRecursive(element.children[i]);
            }else{
                element.remove(element.children[i]);
                element.children[i] = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `children` is a read-only collection. `element.children[i] = null` has no affect to the DOM.

Comment: sorry, it's javascript code for Appcelerator Titanium iOS App

Comment: try iterating in the other direction. And if you remove the top-level node, all its childNodes are also gone. So why do you do this recursively? To me this is just unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @Thomas i can't. I have to remove from the last child.

Comment: On Appcelerator Plaftorm there are memory leak problems. I have to remove all the children to free the memory correctly.

Comment: @WhiteLine sry, seems I didn't look properly.

Comment: @Whiteline, this is a very bad practice to remove children like that. Why so, because your code can easily go in wrong end if you just add another view in that XML file. My suggestion is to define an export method in that controller and use it in parent view. But this is seriously a bad approach.

Comment: @PrashantSaini is not an XML file. It's a container view with children (view , label).

Comment: Then it's more easy to bind a method instead of exporting to from a controller. You should use this approach of deleting views using their IDs (in XML) or vars (in js). I don't know why you are using such a messy code to delete children views when there are more better ways to do it. It would be really helpful if you can provide a screenshot of what views you want to delete as your current code provides no info on how your UI layout looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `remove` also after you come back from the recursive call.

NB: the first `if` is not necessary, as this condition is already checked by the `for` loop. And you can remove the similar check that you do before calling the function recursively, as again the recursive call will check it in its `for` loop:

```
function deleteRecursive(element){
    for(var i = element.children.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
        deleteRecursive(element.children[i]);
        element.remove(element.children[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had done such a thing, but i thought that in this way were eliminated fathers with children still inside.

Comment: The recursive call will delete all descendants, so when you get at the `remove()` call, the node being deleted is empty.

Comment: Thanks, my doubt was just that.

Comment: @trincot there seems to be a small typo (also in the original code). I guess the recursive call should be to "deleteRecursive" and not "testDeleteRecursive" :-)

Comment: Thanks, @JohnDalsgaard!